# how to cons-stream into global stream?

Tags: scheme

I have global variable P1 defined `(define P1 '())`. I need to applying cons-stream of p1 and some-integer.

```
(define P1 '())
(set! P1 (cons-stream P1 some-number)
```

If i do cons-stream multiple time via above.
this result in

```
((((some-number . #<promise>) . #<promise>) . #<promise>) . #<promise>)
```

So i tried this method

```
(define P1 '())
(set! P1 (cons-stream some-number P1)
```

this will give me reverse-list
What i want is a stream with reverse of list generated in the second method.
How will i get this?

Comment: The whole point with streams is delayed execution. You can't get that with updating a global. I'm guessing XY. What problem are you really trying to solve? Usually you do `(cons-stream value expression-that-creates-next-chain)`

Comment: if i cant update update global, if there any way i can convert list into stream? i am thinking that i can update global list and convert list into stream. Its home-work problem where i need update global stream such that it contains (some list of number).

Comment: Belive me. If this is homework and you need to use streams you should not update globals. You won't get good grades on it. `(define (list->stream lst) (if (null? lst) the-empty-stream (cons-stream (car lst) (list->stream (cdr lst)))))` ? (I have no idea what stream library/implementation you're using so it might not be 100% acurate) Usually you make steams like `(define (integers from) (cons-stream from (integers (+ from 1))))`

Comment: It's much more likely that you have wrongly assumed that you are supposed to have a global and update it than it is that you actually are supposed to do that. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?